# How to fix invalid JWT between Keycloak and Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, keycloak

I have a SSO [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) and I want to sign in with it in the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) SSO.
The problem is that the JWT given by Keycloak seems to be invalid for Firebase. Unfortunately, I checked the JWT via https://jwt.io/ and it seems right.

authentificationService.js

```
getToken () {
    console.log(this.keycloakInstance.idToken)
    return this.keycloakInstance.idToken
}
```

main.js

```
firebase.auth.signInWithCustomToken(authentificationService.getToken())
```

You can see Github issue with more information : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2031

Comment: Any news on your issue ?

Comment: I aim the same, any updates?